# Bash CLI is not behaving after upgrading Mac to Catalina

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, command-line-interface, rvm

I was previously on Mojave but was forced to update because of XCode.

When it finished installing, I had to change the default **Login Shell**, because Catalina now uses Z Shell.
[image]

After I did that, my CLI still looks and acts very different:

> **BEFORE:** [image]

This is what it currently looks like:

> **AFTER:**
>   [image]

I googled' `line 33:     __rvm_read_lines _hooks_list <('` and was advised to run: `source ~/.bashrc`. Nothing changed, until I ran `source ./bash_profile` **and it started to somewhat feel better**, but it still not performing commands properly. There is always some error.

[image]

Lastly, **why do I have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` every time?** I just want this to be back to normal.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a Bash script with Zsh. That obviously can't work.

Answer (score -1):

After the upgrade, my CLI actually gave me this message:

> *The default interactive shell is now zsh.
>   To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
>   For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.*

Foolishly, I ran that command, hoping it would go away.

It was fixed by switching back to **`chsh -s /bin/bash`** not `sh`.